# Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported when post to restController

Tags: java, spring-boot

This issue only happend with this controller since i added a self relation in model.

i read and search in other posts and google and any solutions appears to work.

I tried setting @JsonIdentityInfo, adding @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference, inversed order of this tags, adding consumes to the rest method, but anything works

Model:

```
@Entity

@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "code")

@Table (name = "EP7_TRS_CODIGOS")
public class Code implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Id
    @Column (name = "COD_CODIGO")
    private String code;

    @Column (name = "DES_CODIGO")
    private String description;

    @Column (name = "COD_TIPO")
    private String type;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "ID_ORIGEN", referencedColumnName = "ID_ORIGEN")
    private Origin origin;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="COD_CODIGO_OBJ", referencedColumnName = "COD_CODIGO")
    private Code parent;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Code> sons;
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/code",
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
    produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Code> saveOrUpdateCode (@RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @RequestBody Code code){
    logger.info(">>>> Entra en el controlador saveOrUpdateCode");
    if (httpHeaders == null || !authorized(httpHeaders)) {
        logger.error(">>>> Error de autentificacion");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    } 
    return new ResponseEntity<>(cs.save(code), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Origin class

```
@Entity
// @JsonIdentityInfo(
//   generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
//   property = "id")
@Table (name = "EP7_TRS_ORIGEN")
public class Origin implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column (name = "ID_ORIGEN")
    private int id;

    @Column (name = "DES_ORIGEN")
    private String description;

    @Column (name = "COD_TIPO")
    private String type;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany (targetEntity=Code.class, mappedBy="origin", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    private List<Code> codes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add header `Content-type` with value `application/json` when sending post request. Also, you should remove `@JsonManagedReference` from `Origin` class.

Comment: Hello, thank you for response. I have yet added the Content-type: application/json but not work

Comment: I added it. I think the problem is the self relation in Code, this class was working before the implementation of this relation. I tried to manage it with so many changes without results, i'm starting to think it must be removed and change the data model in a better way

Comment: I tried your code, but without Origin field and it is working for me.

Comment: Hi Jesus, see edited answer please, it solves your problem.